# Maven release plugin - How to use shallow git clone

Tags: git, maven, clone, maven-release-plugin, shallow-copy

i'm using the maven release plugin 2.5.3. I'm using git as repo.
I want to use the shallow clone (depth 1) option at the time of release plugin.
I saw the shallow clone option has been introduced in maven-scm-api starting from 1.10.0 version but with default value as false. So how i can override this property using 'shallow' option = true ?
My actual situation is the following: (i added the dependencies of git and scm, otherwise the versions used by release plugin had version 1.9.4 that doesn't contain the shallow option).

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                <!--<arguments>-Dprepare-release=true</arguments>-->
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

Anyway with this config, i'm not able to force the shallow option to true.
I know the maven-release-plugin 3.0.0-M1 has 'true' as default value for shallow option, but i dont want to upgrade the maven plugin version.

Comment: First your dependency in your configuration is wrong cause the install-plugin is not a dependency of maven-release-plugin ... furthermore why do you use `clean install` as preparation goals and don't keep the defaults... Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade to 3.0.0-M1 release plugin version... What is the problem with updating?

Comment: I tried but i got this:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project bo-connector-modules: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]


Anyway how can i use the shallow with 2.5.3?